# How do I calculate a SHA-256 Tomcat 8 DataSourceRealm compatible hash in Java code?

Tags: tomcat, datasource, sha256, jdbcrealm

I'm using Tomcat 8.0.17 with JDK 1.8.0_25. I'm using Derby for the database.

I have a DataSourceRealm working with FORM authentication using SHA-256 digests.

My $WEBAPP/META-INF/context.xml looks like this:

```
<Context> 
  <ResourceLink global="jdbc/demo" name="jdbc/demo" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
         digest="SHA-256"
         dataSourceName="jdbc/demo"
         userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass"
         userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name"/>
</Context>
```

When using the digest tool that comes with Tomcat, I can manually update the users.user_pass column in the database with the output of the digest tool and everything works (note -s 0 since Tomcat does not work with salted hashes):

```
C:\>"%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\digest" -a SHA-256 -s 0 hotdog
hotdog:$1$35602208e86ac7d6b3a63780a9538a9d1763a646d5b9f3930a0548e0983e0ca6

...

ij> update users set user_pass='$1$35602208e86ac7d6b3a63780a9538a9d1763a646d5b9f3930a0548e0983e0ca6' where user_name='demouser';
1 row inserted/updated/deleted
```

Now I am able to log in successfully.

Now how do I programmatically (in Java) generate SHA-256 hashed passwords to insert into the database? I've seen many examples of generating SHA-256 hashes and converting the byte string to hex. But the part that is throwing me off is the beginning of the hash when using the digest tool. It always generates hashes with '$' in the beginning. When converting a hash programmatically and encoding in hex, there will never be '$' characters included in the output (since there is no '$' in hex, only 0-F). But Tomcat seems to work fine with the digest tool output (which includes the dollar signs).

Answer (score 3):

The result of the digester comes out in the format:

> password:salt$iterations$digest

For example, password "1234", 20 character salt and 10 iterations would yield:

> 1234:d83beb29c66cd2f021a469875ffd4c608c25d855$10$eab99fbeedfd7d01b94cd3cf8484a99ad671726faa3e5d48c0699b489aa35658

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it and I guess Tomcat just strips off everything up to the second dollar sign from the digest tool output. So I can generate a SHA-256 hash hex string in Java using Apache Commons:

```
String sha256hex = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(password);
```

EDIT: so what is the significance of the '$' signs in the hash string that the digest tool is generating? I'm going to guess that it's salt-related?

Answer (score 0):

```
    package testapp;
```

`import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

/**
 *
 * @author Martin
 */
public class TestApp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
        testing how to salted sha-256 like tomcat digest.sh -> credential:salt$iterations$hash
        /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/bin/digest.sh -a SHA-256 NonGuesablePassword
NonGuesablePassword:a2eda424107c276748780bca8e7d46256321345e1fd0d0d0bcdbcee72dcc0a4a$1$8f2027b86b0b475be7d09c737995037864a4dbc44d90f24648680169b246a9c7
        */
        String pwd="NonGuesablePassword";
        String salt="a2eda424107c276748780bca8e7d46256321345e1fd0d0d0bcdbcee72dcc0a4a";
        String hash="8f2027b86b0b475be7d09c737995037864a4dbc44d90f24648680169b246a9c7";
         try {
             System.out.println(hash+" 1st iteration hash");
            java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

            md.update(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(salt));
            md.update(pwd.getBytes());

        System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(md.digest())+ " 1st iteration") ; // encrypte sha-256 versie
        System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(md.digest())+ " 2nd iteration") ; // encrypte sha-256 versie

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException na) {
            System.out.println(na.getMessage());

        }

    }

}`

also: tomcat recognizes the 2 $ signs in the userCredCol field when using digest. Without the $ it uses the unsalted version and that's is equal to a salt size of 0 with 1 iteration eg "$1$hash" or "hash" are identical.

ALSO: not all tomcats have the same digest version. pe unlike 8.0.26 the 8.0.14 does not have the possibility for sha-256 with salt. putting salted info in userCredCol wil obviously not work.